# How to count cells that are shaded and greater than a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of shaded cell that i wish to count, but i also want to count those cells that are shaded and greater than zero

I have found some code that writes a formula that counts the cells based off the colour, but i am trying to modify it to add an additional condition. I have tried adding an AND command into the formula to give the additional condition.

```
Function CountColorIf(rSample As Range, rArea As Range) As Long

Dim rAreaCell As Range
Dim lMatchColor As Long
Dim lCounter As Long

lMatchColor = rSample.Interior.Color
For Each rAreaCell In rArea
    If rAreaCell.Interior.Color = lMatchColor And Cells.Value > "0" Then
        lCounter = lCounter + 1
    End If
Next rAreaCell
CountColorIf = lCounter
End Function
```

I added the    And Cells.Value > "0"   piece to existing code

As it is searching each "rAreaCell" can i not add an AND to also identify if it is greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

the cell you need to check is rAreaCell, you can not use cells

```
If rAreaCell.Interior.Color = lMatchColor And rAreaCell.Value > "0" Then
```